# Getting a null value in Firebase rest response

Tags: rest, null, firebase, restful-url

I am trying to create a restful service using firebase as backend. I have created a sample app and when I hit this url [ https://poctest1.firebaseio.com/rest.json ], I am getting the following response.

```
[
  null,
  {
    "value": "test1"
  },
  {
    "value": "test 2"
  }
]
```

Why am I getting a null on top, I haven't inserted any.

[image]

Help me to figure this out. Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you inserted that data? It looks like you added an array, then removed element `0`. Note that Firebase has special (and sometimes very non-intuitive) handling of arrays: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase . In general it is better to find another data structure, such as a collection based on Firebase's `push` method.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No I manually inserted into firebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is how Firebase's SDKs deserialize array-like structures. [Firebase's documentation on arrays](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase) explains it:

> when data is read using `val()` or via the [REST api](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest), if the data looks like an array, Firebase will render it as an array. In particular, if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values, then Firebase will render it as an array.

Since your array doesn't have an element at index 0, Firebase injects a `null` for that.

In general when using Firebase you should try to not use arrays, for the reasons mentioned in the documentation I linked above. If you find your *must* use an array, make sure that you always update the entire array in Firebase. So don't try to manipulate specific items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

add a value at the zero position, then you will not get the null value.